# How do I use less CPU with loops?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, infinite-loop

I've got a loop that looks like this:

```
while (elapsedTime < refreshRate) 
{
    timer.stopTimer();
    elapsedTime=timer.getElapsedTime();
}
```

I read something similar to this elsewhere ([[C Main Loop without 100% cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222574/c-main-loop-without-100-cpu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222574/c-main-loop-without-100-cpu)), but this loop is running a high resolution timer that must be accurate. So how am I supposed to not take up 100% CPU while still keeping it high resolution?

Comment: what kind of operations does that loop perform ? Why do you need high resolution ?

Comment: I've said this many times in other threads.  Windows is not a real time operating system.  If you need high resolution, then what are you going to do if you hit a bad rash of page faults and your timer doesn't fire soon enough.

Comment: I'm using QueryPerformanceCounter, which uses the hardware

Comment: @Mark - that won't entirely protect you.

Comment: How do video players implement timers to make sure they have the correct frame rate without using 100% CPU? Should I follow that example instead?

Comment: Use Sleep. But it has 10 milliseconds precision.

Comment: You usually use several threads: file reading, demuxing, decoding, etc. Use double/triple buffering to update display, with multimedia timers (as tovare already pointed). Most users will not have problems if you loose a couple of frames, also this will not be a problem at all with recent hardware.

Comment: @Ismael I heard somewhere that multimedia timers were deprecated, which is why I decided to use performance counters instead. Should I just ignore this?

Comment: @Mark For now its seems that MS didn't mark them as deprecated, so it should be fine using them. Until MS updates the documentation, marking them as deprecated, and/or provides a better alternatives IMHO it is safe to use them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Main Loop without 100% cpu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222574/c-main-loop-without-100-cpu)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't busy-wait but rather have the OS tell you when the time has passed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712704(VS.85).aspx

High resolution timers (Higher than 10 ms)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163996.aspx

Answer (score 4):

When you say that your timer must be "accurate", how accurate do you actually need to be?  If you only need to be accurate to the nearest millisecond, then you can add a half-millisecond sleep inside the loop.  You can also add a dynamically-changing sleep statement based off of how much time you have left to sleep.  Think of something like (pseudocode):

```
int time_left = refreshRate - elapsedTime;
while (time_left > 0) {
    if (time_left > threshhold)
        sleep_for_interval(time_left / 2);
    update_timestamp(elapsedTime);
    time_left = refreshRate - elapsedTime;
}
```

With that algorithm, your code will sleep for short bursts if it detects that you still have a while to wait.  You would want to run some tests to find an optimal value for `threshhold` that balances CPU usage savings for risk of overshoot (caused by your app losing the CPU when it sleeps and not getting any more CPU time in time).

The other method for high-resolution timing is to use a hardware timer that triggers an periodic interrupt.  Your interrupt handler would send a signal to some thread that it needs to wake up and do something, after which it goes back to sleep and waits for the next signal to come in.

Real-Time Operating Systems have ways to do this sort of things built into the OS.  If you're doing Windows programming and need extremely precise timing, be aware that that's not the sort of thing that a general-purpose OS like Windows handles very well.

Comment: sleep only gurantees that it will sleep at least as long as the request. It may be longer before the processes is re-sheduled.

Comment: It's just pseudo-code.  The call to `sleep` was meant to illustrate what the function does, not necessarily reference the actual library function with that name.  I'll change the pseudo-code to avoid confusion.

Comment: Sleep has 10 milliseconds precision. You can't sleep for half of millisecond.

Answer (score 3):

Look at some timers delivered by the OS, like POSIX `usleep`.
On the other hand, if you need hyper precision, your code will not work either, because the OS will break this loop after it would exhaust its process time quantum and jump to the kernel space to make some system tasks. To this end you would need some special OS with interruptable kernel and tools delivered by it; look for RTOS keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you yield to the OS in some fashion. This allows the OS to take a break from your program and do something else.

Obviously this is OS dependent, but:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
#endif

void yield(void)
{
    #ifdef _WIN32
        Sleep(0);
    #else
        usleep(1);
    #endif
}
```

Insert a call to yield before you stop the timer. The OS will report less time usage by your program.

Keep in mind, of course, this makes your timer "less accurate", because it might not update as frequently as possible. But you really shouldn't depend on extreme-accuracy, it's far too difficult. Approximations are okay.